# How to add data to both: Category id and Name Category from one Html.LabelFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

In the view Create i want to  add a new product. I need from the drop down list to select the category name. The problem is, that  i have in the table Products add only the category id. And how me add and name too of category?

Structure my DB:

Table Brand: idbrand, name.

Table Make: idbrand, namebrand, idmake, name, price, urlmake.

I do the following:

```
    // GET: /ShopManager/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.BrandID = new SelectList(db.Brand, "BrandID", "Name");
        return View();
    } 

    //
    // POST: /ShopManager/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Make make)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Make.AddObject(make);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        ViewBag.BrandID = new SelectList(db.Brand, "BrandID", "Name", make.BrandID);
        return View(make);
    }



  @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
   @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
   <fieldset>
    <legend>Марка телефона</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BrandID, "Бренд")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("BrandID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BrandID)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, "Марка телефона")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price, "Цена")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UrlMake, "Изображение")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UrlMake)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UrlMake)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Создать" />
    </p>
  </fieldset>


  <div>
  @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
  </div>
```

How me add in Table Make BrandID and Name of Brand(name of Category)?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a Brand table it's not necessary to store brand's name in the Make also, you could get that with a simple join. Anyway if you really want to do that in the Create you can set it as the following code

```
make.NameBrand = db.Brand.Where(b => b.idbrand == make.idbrand).SingleOrDefault().namebrand;
```

Comment: I undestand. And how me add make.NameBrand add on table Make on View Create?